# BMA and RJMCMC predictive performance

Tags: bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo, model-averaging, reversible-jump

We have a family of statistical models, with parameter spaces of different dimensions, which we aggregated through standard Bayesian Model Averaging (BMA). Experiments using training and test sets show that the predictive performance of the aggregated model is good, when compared to available alternatives. My question is if, for predictive purposes, it is worth investigating inference on the space of our family of models using Reversible Jump Markov Chain Monte Carlo (RJMCMC) techniques. Should we expect a gain in predictive performance using RJMCMC instead of BMA? Are there any known examples in the literature showing that this could be the case?

Comment: Hi! I doubt reversible jump would help in such a case as BMA runs a separate MCMC over each model and _then_ aggregates. Unless there is a strong connection between the models that makes reversible jump exceptionally efficient, there is no reason to believe that the estimation of the predictive would be improved that way.

Comment: Thank you for your insight, Xi'an!